# if Condition hide or appear table row in Aeroo Reports

Tags: if-statement, report, show-hide, openerp-7

I'm creating a report ( module ) in openERP using Aeroo report

for the report template i use liberoffice

i want to hide and show a table row depending on the result of (If condition )

for example if type= A then show the row 
if type=B then hide a row

help will be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: after trying i figure out how to do it, its simple just add two more rows above and below the row you want to hidde and show depending on your if statment .... in the abov row add your if statment and in the below row close your if statment by /if   i hope this will help

Comment: would you please explain it in more details